# Why does creating a new face int layer break Unwrap Reset?

Tags: python, add-on, bmesh, layers

EDIT: This apparently is a bug (https://developer.blender.org/T52723)

However, I'm still creating bmeshes in the draw method of my panels which is bad practice, but not the cause of this problem.

---

I've been developing an add-on for Re-Volt file types for a while.

I'm not sure if I discovered a bug or if I'm doing something wrong:
As soon as I call `bm.faces.layers.int.new("LayerName")`, the UV Unwrap Reset operator starts behaving weirdly.

Usually, when you reset the UV on a cube, you get the faces mapped as squares.
After creating a new int layer on the bmesh, it starts mapping faces to lines or other weird shapes that sometimes go beyond the UV bounds.

[image: example uv image]

I create those int layers to store flags for each face. The layers are created upon import and in Edit mode. I made a tool panel for setting those flags. It all works fine, it just breaks the `bpy.ops.uv.reset()` operator.

Launching Blender with --debug-all also didn't reveal any interesting details. Everything in the logs looks like it's supposed to.

I also tried opening the Blender files with that problem in older and newer versions than 2.78 and the problem persists there, it seems to be in the mesh.

Here's a .blend with the problem: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47471

Here's the wider context of creating a new int layer (panel in the 3D view):

```
class RevoltFacePropertiesPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Face Properties"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
    bl_context = "mesh_edit"
    bl_category = "Re-Volt"

    selection = None
    selected_face_count = None

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return (context.object is not None)

    def draw(self, context):
        pass
        obj = context.object
        mesh = obj.data
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
        flags = bm.faces.layers.int.get("RVFlags") or bm.faces.layers.int.new("RVFlags")
        texture = bm.faces.layers.int.get("RVTexture") or bm.faces.layers.int.new("RVTexture")
```

Here's the section on GitHub if that helps: https://github.com/Dummiesman/HabitatB/blob/dev/io_scene_habitatb/panels.py#L104

Please tell me if I could provide more information. I'd be really thankful if someone has an idea.

Comment: Changing ID data in a panel's draw method is a NO NO.  (will throw an error for `obj.location = (0, 0, 0)` for example).   The draw method runs many times (esp if mouse is over),  put in a print statement to check.  You will be making multiple instances of `bmesh.from_edit_mesh()`  [Have a look at](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56452/15543) on how to make a global dic and use one edit mode bmesh for the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Blender bug. It has been fixed: [developer.blender.org](https://developer.blender.org/rBd827186c17c98bbde418f134e562a99722a141c5)